# Segmentation fault (core dump)?

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am attempting to access methods in a tokenizer.c using the header tokenizer.h file, but I can't call the "tokenize" method in my main method without receiving the `Segmentation fault(core dump)` error when I input something to the console.
I've tried rearranging pointers and memory allocation, I've also received help from classmates. I still receive the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tokenizer.h"
#include "history.h"

int main(){
  int noexit = 1;
  while(noexit){
    char input[100];
    printf("> ");

    fgets(input, 100, stdin);

    if(*input == '0'){
      noexit = 0;
    }
    else{
      char** tokens = tokenize(input);
      print_tokens(tokens);
      free_tokens(tokens);
    }
  }
  //past output
  /*printf(space_char(' '));*/
}
```

This is my main method, in file uimain.c. This is not finished, but only works when I remove the

```
char** tokens = tokenize(input);
      print_tokens(tokens);
      free_tokens(tokens);
```

block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tokenizer.h"

int space_char(char c){
  if(c == '\t' || c == ' '){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int non_space_char(char c){
  if(c != '\t' || c != ' '){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

char *word_start(char *str){
  int i = 0;
  while(space_char(str[i]) == 1){
    i++;
  }
  return &str[i];
}

char *word_terminator(char *word){
  word  = word_start(word);
  int i = 0;
  
  while(non_space_char(word[i]) == 1){
    i = i+1;
  }
  
  return &word[i];
}

int count_words(char *str){
  int count = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while(str[i] != '\0') {
      if(space_char(str[i]) && non_space_char(str[i + 1]))
    count++;
      i++;
    }
    count++;
  return count;
}

char  *copy_str(char *inStr, short len){
  int i = 0;
  //MALLOC FOR NEW STR :D
  char *outStr = malloc((len+1) *sizeof(char));

  while(i<=len){
    outStr[i]  = inStr[i];
    i= i+1;
  }
  return outStr;
}

char **tokenize(char *str){
  int i = 0;
  printf("%s","int i");
  int len;
  printf("%s","len");
  int all = count_words(str);
  printf("%s","all");
  char **tokens = malloc((all+1) * sizeof(char*));
  printf("%s","tokens");
  char *pointer = str;
  printf("%s","pointer");

  while(i < all+1){
    pointer = word_start(pointer);
    printf("%s","word_start");
    len = (word_terminator(pointer) - word_start(pointer));
    printf("%s","len");
    tokens[i] = copy_str(pointer, len);
    pointer = word_terminator(pointer);
    i = i + 1;
  }
  tokens[i] = 0;
  return tokens;
}

void print_tokens(char **tokens){
  int i = 0;
  while(tokens[i] !=  NULL){
    printf("%s\n", tokens[i]);
    i =  i + 1;
  }
}

void free_tokens(char **tokens){
  int i = 0;
  //can't pass  len as param  :D
  while(tokens[i] != 0){
    free(tokens[i]);
    i = i + 1;
  }
  free(tokens);
}
```

This is tokenizer.c

```
#ifndef _TOKENIZER_
#define _TOKENIZER_


/* Return true (non-zero) if c is a whitespace characer
   ('\t' or ' ').  
   Zero terminators are not printable (therefore false) */
int space_char(char c);

/* Return true (non-zero) if c is a non-whitespace 
   character (not tab or space).  
   Zero terminators are not printable (therefore false) */ 
int non_space_char(char c);

/* Returns a pointer to the first character of the next 
   space-separated word in zero-terminated str.  Return a zero pointer if 
   str does not contain any words. */
char word_start(char *str); 

/* Returns a pointer terminator char following *word */
char *word_terminator(char *word);

/* Counts the number of words in the string argument. */
int count_words(char *str);

/* Returns a fresly allocated new zero-terminated string 
   containing <len> chars from <inStr> */
char *copy_str(char *inStr, short len);

/* Returns a freshly allocated zero-terminated vector of freshly allocated 
   space-separated tokens from zero-terminated str.
   For example, tokenize("hello world string") would result in:
     tokens[0] = "hello"
     tokens[1] = "world"
     tokens[2] = "string" 
     tokens[3] = 0
*/
char **tokenize(char* str);

/* Prints all tokens. */
void print_tokens(char **tokens);

/* Frees all tokens and the vector containing themx. */
void free_tokens(char **tokens);

#endif
```

This is tokenizer.h, just in case

Comment: Use a debugger. It will instantly tell you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. That is the minimum debugging you should do and should post in the question.

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` (gcc & I think clang) is great for debugging these problems.

Comment: Well, for one, `char word_start(char *str); ` certainly doesn't live up to its comment description. That function should return a `char*` not `char`

Comment: regarding: `char *outStr = malloc((len+1) *sizeof(char));`  1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.  2) the function: `malloc()` expects a `size_t` parameter, not an `short` parameter.  3) the function: `malloc()` can fail, so should always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );`  The cleanup and exit the program

Comment: regarding statements like: `printf("%s","word_start");`  This will sit in the `stdout` stream buffer until either: `program exits`, or `buffer overflow` or `an input operation` is performed. or `fflush()` is called or a '\n' is output.  I.E. this will not be displayed on the terminal in a 'timely' manner.  Suggest: `printf("%s\n","word_start");`

Comment: The 'home grfown' header file: `history.h` is being included, but that contents of that file are not posted.  So how are we to reproduce your problem when critical code is not posted

Comment: regarding: `while(i < all+1){`  the variable `all` already contains a full count of the number of words in the input string, so adding an additional `1` will cause the loop to access beyond the end of the input string.  The result is undefined behavior (and as you have seen) a seg fault event.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I tried to compile your code.

In first place, in the `tokenizer.h` file, `start_word()` function is declared to return a char, but in the `tokenizer.c` file, is defined to return a `char *`. According to the description in `tokenizer.h`, change it to return a `char *`.

```
/* Returns a pointer to the first character of the next 
   space-separated word in zero-terminated str.  Return a zero pointer if 
   str does not contain any words. */
char *word_start(char *str);
```

Now, looking at the `tonkenize()` function in `tokenizer.c` file, the `printf()` function is not used correctly. To learn how to use `printf()`, check [this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm).

1. Change the specifier according to the type of the variable you are printing. The `"%s"` only works for strings;
2. Then, add the `'\n'` (new line character). The bytes in the buffer will only be printed after a `'\n'` is reached;
3. Finally, remove the quotation marks in the variable names. In C, quotation marks always represent strings.

Here are some examples:

```
int i = 0;
printf("%d\n", i);
int len;
printf("%d\n", len);
int all = count_words(str);
printf("%d\n", all);
// (...)
```

If you did not meant to print the variables and these `printf()` calls are only for testing, remove the first argument (but don forget the `'\n'` character).

```
int i = 0;
printf("i\n");
int len;
printf("len\n");
int all = count_words(str);
printf("all\n");
// (...)
```

After these `printf()` calls, memory is allocated with `malloc()`.

```
char **tokens = malloc((all+1) * sizeof(char*));
```

If `tokens` variable represents an array of strings null-terminated and the variable `all` represents the number of strings variable `tokens` has, it is correct. The problem is you did not check if the memory allocation was successful.

```
char **tokens = malloc((all+1) * sizeof(char*));
if (tokens == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: allocating memory\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Now, about the while loop.

1. You start by getting the start of the word and then you calculate the length, calling `word_start()` again, but you already know the start of the word;
2. Then, you copy the string and move to the end of the word, calling again `word_terminator()` function instead of just storing the previous result. Note that the end of word is the start in the next iteration;
3. The `i = i + 1;` instruction can be replaced by `i++;`;
4. The range of iteration must be from zero to the number of strings less one.

Here is my suggestion for the `tokenize()` function.

```
char **tokenize(char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int all = count_words(str);
    char **tokens = malloc((all+1) * sizeof(char*));
    if (tokens == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: allocating memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    char *start = str, *end = str;
    while (i < all) {
        start = word_start(end);
        end = word_terminator(start);
        tokens[i] = copy_str(start, end - start);
        i++;
    }
    tokens[i] = NULL;
    return tokens;
}
```

Now, about the `copy_str()` function.

1. You forgot, again, to check if the memory allocation was successful;
2. The range of the while loop is from zero to the string's length less one;
3. You forgot to null-terminate the string before returning.

Here is my suggestion for the `copy_str()` function.

```
char *copy_str(char *inStr, short len) {
    int i = 0;
    char *outStr = malloc((len+1) *sizeof(char));
    if (outStr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: allocating memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    while (i < len) {
        outStr[i] = inStr[i];
        i++;
    }
    outStr[i] = '\0';
    return outStr;
}
```

Looking the way `word_start()` and `word_terminator()` were implemented, we can clearly understand that if I call `word_start("     ");` or `word_terminator("asdfg");`, segmentation fault will occur. That is because you are only checking if you reached a non-space/space character, respectively. You need to check for the `'\0'` (null character) to break the loop at the end of the string.

```
char *word_start(char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    while (space_char(str[i]) == 1) {
        if ( str[i] == '\0' )
            return NULL;
        i++;
    }
    return &str[i];
}

char *word_terminator(char *word) {
    word  = word_start(word);
    if ( word == NULL )
        return NULL;
    int i = 0;
    while (non_space_char(word[i]) == 1) {
        if ( word[i] == '\0' )
            return &word[i-1];
        i++;
    }
    return &word[i];
}
```

After compiling your program again, here is the result.

```
$ ./uimain
> Miguel Carvalho 22
Miguel Carvalho 22


> ^C
$
```

Although the program works, the code can be improved. Here are some notes.

1. The C standard library contain some useful functions for this program. Search for `ctype.h` and `string.h`;
2. The `count_words()` function is not counting correctly. Instead of using `space_char()` and `non_space_char()` functions in the loop, try to use `word_start()` and `word_terminator()` functions until `NULL` is returned.

Comment: Very good response :)  Don't forget about the suspicious "if(*input == '0'){}" line!  I'm guessing the OP meant `if(*input == 0)`.  Which can be simplified to `if(!(*input))`

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but I'm still receiving the same error :( I even changed everything to what you sent but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @area are you sure you changed your code correctly? Are you sure the while loops iterate in the correct range? Are you sure you did not forget any null-terminator after the while loops (`NULL` for the array of strings and `'\0'` for the strings)? Verify again. Put some `printf()` calls (do not forget the `'\n'`) to detect in witch part of the code segmentation fault occurs. Do not insert extra spaces when running your program because, for each extra space (before, after and between words), `count_words()` function counts one word.

Comment: @MiguelCarvalho yes, when I use the debugger it seems I receive the Segmentation fault (core dump) error when the tokenize() function uses copy_str(), but I'm not sure why. I'm sure I wrote the malloc statement correctly. In fact, I tried writing it exactly like the one you suggested and it threw the error.

Comment: @arae the `copy_str()` function is only called in `tokenize()` function. Given a certain input, `"abc dfg hij"` for example, catch in witch iteration of the while loop in `tokenize()` function segfault occurs. If it occurs in the first iteration, try to understand if the string passed as argument is `"abc"` in fact. If it occurs after the last iteration (after `"hij"`), that's because the variable `all` in the while loop in `tokenize()` function, witch is the return of `count_words()` function, does not match the number of words...

Comment: ... In this last case, try to fix the `count_words()` or check if `start = word_start(end);` returns `NULL` and break the loop.